# weight matrices and cost in each epoch of RNN using estimator API of tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have used Estimator API for training a RNN model, and I wanna plot the cost/epoch figure and obtain the best model weight matrices. Is it possible in Estimator API?
here is the code:

```
   classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: input_fn_train(train_x, label_train, batch_size),steps=train_steps)


   eval_result = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn_eval(test_x, label_test, batch_size))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. What you have to do is to configure your Estimator to produce the relevant information that would be useful for you to decide which weights you want to keep. This can be done through checkpoints. which are the 'saves' of your model.
Passing to the Estimator `config=` some configurations would be useful.

Here is an example with a custom Estimator:

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    #Some code is here that gives you the output of your model from where
    #you get your predictions.
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN or tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        #Some more code is here
        loss = #your loss function here
        tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        #More code here that train your model
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        #Again more code that you use to get some evaluation metrics
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        #Code...
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                      predictions=predictions,
                                      loss=loss,
                                      train_op=train_op,
                                      eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


configuration = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_summary_steps=10,
                                       keep_checkpoint_max=30,
                                       save_checkpoints_steps=10,
                                       log_step_count_steps=10)

custom_estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn,
                               model_dir='model_dir',
                               config=configuration)

custom_estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=10000)
```

`save_summary_steps`: Actually you can think of this like after how many steps your
estimator would update your summaries. This can be useful so you can plot your loss
every 10 steps.

`save_checkpoints_steps`: After how many steps your estimator would be saved at the present state.

You can find these checkpoints in the `model_dir`.

If you are using a canned Estimator i think the summaries are predefined but the loss function is already there so you just have to configure how frequently you want to print your summaries and how often you want to save your model state.

Comment: thanks to your answer, it works. but there is just a written error in the above code, in the line tf.summaries.scalar('loss', loss), tf.summaries must be change to tf.summary.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you. Mark this as a solution.